# Changing margin-top also affects sidebar (other places)

Tags: html, css

I've made a sidebar in html but there is a problem when I've added some images and attempted to change the margins. This also applies the margin to the sidebar. I've tried changing the position from fixed to relative, absolute, etc. but this does not help. The sidebar should maintain its original 100% height, but the images' margin-top of 400px also applies to the sidebar, which is 400px down from where it should be. Thanks in advance

```
.sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    left: -250px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #313B4A;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bolder;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: 0.7s ease;
}
.sidebar header{
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #4F6D7A;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 800px;
    line-height: 75px;
    background:  #DBE9EE;
    user-select: none;
}
.sidebar ul a{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 65px;
    color: #dceedc;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}


label #btn, label #close{
position: absolute;
}

#tickbox:checked ~ .sidebar{
    left:0;
}

#tickbox:checked ~ label #btn{
    left:250px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#tickbox:checked ~ label #close{
    left:195px;
    
}




html {
   font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.gallery { 

    margin-top: 200px;
    
    padding: 20px; 
    
    display: flex; 
    
    flex-direction: row; 
}

.gallery figure { 
        
    margin: auto; 
    
    width: 250px; 
    
    text-align: center; 
    
    } 
    

.gallery img{

    height: 200px;

    width: 275px; 
       
    }
```

Oops, forgot to add the HTML!

```
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="tickbox">
    <label for="tickbox">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"id ="btn"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-times"id ="close"></i>
    </label>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <header>KeyQuarters</header>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="/KeyboardProject/Home/home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/KeyboardProject/Group Buys/gb.html">Group Buys</a></li>
        <li><a href="/KeyboardProject/Keycaps/kc.html">Keycaps</a></li>
        <li><a href="/KeyboardProject/Switches/switch.html">Switches</a></li>
        <li><a href="/KeyboardProject/Deskmats/deskmats.html">Deskmats</a></li>
        <li><a href="/KeyboardProject/Kits/kit.html">Kits</a></li>
        <li><a href="/KeyboardProject/Accessories/access.html">Accessories</a></li> 
        
        </ul>
    </div> 

    
<div class="gallery">
<figure>
    <img src="test1.png" alt="keeb1">
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="test2.jpg" alt="keeb2">
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="test2.jpg" alt="keeb2">
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="test2.jpg" alt="keeb2">
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="test2.jpg" alt="keeb2">
</figure>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Ok, But where is your HTML code??

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!